# App Icon not appearing after MDM installation by client

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm, appicon

Our app is published to the app store. It is an iphone app.

One of our clients is pushing our app via his MDM so that his employees can access it on their ipad- our client has a Volume Purchase Program from Apple(I don't have information about what his MDM is). Our app logo does not appear on their iPad after MDM installation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfQLF.png)

Is there a reason for that? They contacted apple support but were asked to talk to the developers.

Should we as developers provide images for ipad so that the icon appears? when we were publishing the app it did not ask us for ipad images since the app was for iphone.

Please let me know.

Comment: You should always provide the full suite of icon sizes; it is just simpler. iPhone apps can be installed on an iPad

Answer (score 0):

All iPhone apps can be installed on iPad devices (unless they have a specific `UIDeviceCapabilities` entry that prevents it).

If your bundle doesn't include an iPad icon then you won't see an icon on an iPad.

You will need to update your app to include iPad icons to resolve this issue.